# Variable in find command set to new variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, find, variable

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
inputNum="$1"

files=($(find /dir/to/check -mtime $inputNum))
```

Basically the idea is that I can use an input parameter to set the number of days to find files and set it to a variable array.  I am not sure on the syntax to make this readable in bash.

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `find` is not post-processable reliably unless you use `-print0` instead of `-print` (`-print` implied when no action is specified).

To post-process the output of `find -print0` and store the file paths in an array:

With bash4.4+:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(find /dir/to/check -mtime "$inputNum" -print0)
```

With older versions:

```
files=()
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  files=("${files[@]}" "$file")
done < <(find /dir/to/check -mtime "$inputNum" -print0)
```

More generally, you'd want to read the recommendations at: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/zsh) instead of bash, then it's a lot easier. Zsh can match files based on their attributes through [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
files=(/dir/to/check/**/*(Dm$inputNum))
```

`**/*` searches subdirectories recursively. The parentheses after `*` contain glob qualifiers: `D` to include dot files, and `m` to match files based on their modification time in days like `find -mtime` (you can also choose a different unit and make the time a limit, e.g. `(Dmm-$min)` acts like `find -mmin -$min`).

Zsh is preinstalled on macOS. On most other unix systems (in particular most Linux distributions), it's available as a package but not installed by default.